# PermissionOverwrites doesn't have function edit/create in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was following a page on the discord.js website, but after copying exactly what it says, I get an error:

> TypeError: message.channel.permissionOverwrites.create is not a function

```
message.channel.permissionOverwrites.create(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: false
});
```

Above is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you are using discord.js v12, but reading docs for v13 (current stable branch). See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/general/welcome) for the right docs.

In discord.js v12 use [`GuildChannel.updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) or [`GuildChannel.createOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createOverwrite).

```js
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: false
});
```

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^12.5.3`.</sub>

Comment: Ah ok, thanks it worked! :D I was using the wrong docs.